# CentOS 7.6 Computer Freezes When Changing Display Settings

Tags: linux, display, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7, gnome3

I am using three monitors and am having an issue where the primary monitor is off to the far left. When I go into the Gnome settings and try and move the monitors around, it freezes. If I unhook and rehook the monitors, it freezes. I was hoping there is a way to manually do it.

The system is using a MSI 970 gaming mobo (bad choice,) an AMD r9 380, and an FX-6300 CPU, and it is booting off a 120GB Kingston SSD

I have installed amdgpu for RHEL 7.6/CENTOS 7.6 and still have the issue, though the system does perform better, though over-all it is slow. It is a fresh install.

---

When I say that the computer is freezing, I do mean that it is freezing, mouse intput barely receives location, keyboard stops ability outputting, and the mouse's scroll wheel and buttons do nothing.